# Placing a time limit on a process in C++

Tags: c++, time, limit, turbo-c++, bgi

I'm trying to make a 1-minute animation of stripes in C++. I made this with **TurboC++7 by Akki**. I can't seem to make the **clock()** function work to my needs. What I want achieve is to be able to set a 60-second time limit on the animation/program execution. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this?

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <graphics.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void main(){
     clock_t start, point;
     int gDriver = DETECT, gMode, errCode, tme;
     clrscr();
     initgraph(&gDriver, &gMode, "C:\\TC\\BGI");

 errCode = graphresult();

 if (errCode != grOk){
  cout << "Graphics error:\n" << grapherrormsg(errCode);
  cout << "\n\nPress any key to continue...";
  getch();
  exit(1);
 }

 setbkcolor(0);

 do{
  start = clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  int x = 1, y = rand() % 480, r = rand() % 21;
  setcolor(rand() % 16);
  do{
       if(kbhit())
        break;
       circle(x, y, r);
       x++;
  } while (x != 639);

  x = rand() % 640, y = 1, r = rand() % 21;
  setcolor(rand() % 16);
  do{
       if(kbhit())
        break;
       circle(x, y, r);
       y++;
  } while (y != 479);

  x = 639, y = rand() % 480, r = rand() % 21;
  setcolor(rand() % 16);
  do{
       if (kbhit())
        break;
       circle(x, y, r);
       x--;
  } while (x != 1);

  x = rand() % 640, y = 479, r = rand() % 21;
  setcolor(rand() % 16);
  do{
       if (kbhit())
        break;
       circle(x, y, r);
       y--;
  } while (y != 1);
  point = clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  if ((point - start) >= 10)
      break;
  else
       tme += point - start;
 } while (!kbhit());

 getch();
 closegraph();
}
```

Comment: This is operating system specific.

Comment: if the program can't run for more than 60 seconds total, the line `start = clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC` should be outside (just before) the do-while loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
point = clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
if ((point - start) >= 10)
    break;
```

Here your time limit is 10 *CPU* seconds, not 60 seconds as you required.
Also, use `time()` to get real time rather than CPU time.

As @rpattiso commented, you should review whether the line `start = clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;` should be put before or inside the `do ... while` loop.